# Extra argument in call error when running on device

Tags: arrays, function, swift, arguments

When initializing an array in this way:

```
var result = [Double](count: N, repeatedValue: 0)
```

and

```
var result = [String](count: N, repeatedValue:"")
```

or when using an initializer of a class I wrote:

```
let result = Matrix(rows: N, columns: N)
```

I get an error when I run it on a device saying that the second argument is extra. Although, if I run it in the simulator, it works properly. What's frustrating further is that similar code is being called somewhere else and isn't causing any problems. What can I do to fix this?

**Update 1**

I should point out that the above examples are in completely separate scopes.

Comment: No, no, no, the examples are in completely separate scopes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Int(N)`. If `N` is `Int64` it will work in 64-bit architecture, like simulator, but will not work in 32-bit architectures like iPhone 4, 4s, 5. `Int` is `typedef` of `Int64` or `Int32` depending on architecture.

Error messages like "second argument is extra" is still quite misleading. It usually means one of your arguments is of a wrong type.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the error was due to `N` being `__CLPK_integer`.